# htaccess redirect http://domain and http://www.domain to https://www.domain, excluding specified subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Goal:

- Redirect any HTTP request **with or without** WWW, to the matching page at https_www.domain.com EXCEPT for requests containing subdomain.domain.com which should be unaffected.

(I'm using underscores in place of :// because my post was being detected as spam, otherwise)

Examples:

- http_domain.com > https_www.domain.com
- http_domain.com* > https_www.domain.com*
- http_www.domain.com > https_www.domain.com
- http_www.domain.com* > https_www.domain.com\anything
- http_subdomain.domain.com > http_subdomain.domain.com
- http_subdomain.domain.com* > http_subdomain.domain.com*
- https_subdomain.domain.com > http_subdomain.domain.com
- https_subdomain.domain.com* > http_subdomain.domain.com*

I thought the following would do it, but it didn't work:

// redirect any request for http_domain.com or http_www.domain.com to https_www.domain.com

// condition 3 should exclude subdomain.domain.com from being affected by the rewrite rule

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTPS} off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$  [NC] 
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any idea why that doesn't accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond www.%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(www\..+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

- The first line checks if the scheme is **http** (https==off)
- The second line excludes the subdomain from https redirectiom (host=!"admin.domain.com")
- The third line matches the host value  **www.domain.com** or **domain.com** .and automatically adds www to non-www so our %1 always contains **www.domain.com** .

Comment: Wow - that's great, thank you. I will test and report back ASAP. Thank you so much for your time and the detailed explanation.

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and it was resulting in https://www.subdomain.domain.com. So, apparently the exclusion isn't working. Can hosting configuration result in this kind of complication, or is there a formatting issue with the directives?

Comment: Replace **admin.domain.com** with **subdomain.domain.com** in the 2nd cond

Comment: The subdomain actually is "admin", so that should have been okay.

Comment: Okay, i think your borwser has cached your previous redirects, Try clearing them.

Comment: I did a browser reset and private browsing session prior to testing. =\ I know that method works because as soon as I commented out your suggestion and reset again, the pages load normally.